# $add with some fields as Null returning sum value as Null

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

These are the documents in my collection

```
{ "_id" : 1, "quizzes" : [ 10, 6, 7 ], "labs" : [ 5, 8 ], "final" : 80, "midterm" : 75 ,"extraMarks":10}
{ "_id" : 2, "quizzes" : [ 9, 10 ], "labs" : [ 8, 8 ], "final" : 95, "midterm" : 80 }
{ "_id" : 3, "quizzes" : [ 4, 5, 5 ], "labs" : [ 6, 5 ], "final" : 78, "midterm" : 70 }
```

Only Document 1 has a field extra marks:

Now i have to make a projection as a sum of "final"+"midterm"+"extraMarks"

I have written a query for projection as follows:

```
db.students.aggregate([    {      $project: {          examTotal: { $add: [ "$final", "$midterm","$extraMarks" ] }      }    } ])
```

This query is giving me correct result for Document1 and for Doc2 and Doc3, as the field doesnt exist its giving sum as null.

Is it possible to check if the field is not null and add in the query itself..Any suggestions for this?

Is there any functionality similar to nvl (in SQL) in the queries Mongo DB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do two projections, the first using [$ifNull](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) which is similar to nvl:

```
db.students.aggregate([
  { $project: { final: 1, midterm: 1, extraMarks: { $ifNull: [ "$extraMarks", 0 ] } } }, 
  { $project: { examTotal: { $add: [ "$final", "$midterm","$extraMarks" ] } } } 
])
```

Comment: You can shorten your pipeline to one stage:
  `{ "$project": { "final": 1, "midterm": 1, "examTotal": { "$add": [ "$final", "$midterm", { "$ifNull":  [ "$extraMarks", 0 ] } ] } } }`

Comment: @user3100115..Thanks this is very helpful as im i doing the whole processing on the java side Single prjection is very useful...

Comment: @user3100115...Is it possible to get only first two records..and ignore the third in the above query?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$match` stage, add it to the beginning of your pipeline
`{$match: {"your_field":{$exists: true}}}`

Comment: Thanks @Dummy..Is this the query?

Comment: db.students.aggregate([   {$match: {"extraMarks":{$exists: true}}}, {      $project: {          examTotal: { $add: [ "$final", "$midterm","$extraMarks" ] }      }    } ]?

Comment: The match stage will filter out any documents which have no field "extraMarks" if your pipeline looks like that for the match stage,what I meant in my answer is that, you can specify a match stage like I did to select documents which must contain the mentioned fields, any documents which don't have the mentioned field will be "discarded"

Comment: But i want the result to be as follows:  doc1: sum==165(80+75+10) doc2: sum=175,doc3 : sum =148

Comment: It is the match stage in the aggregation framework, it accepts the expression you normally pass to the `find ()` method. And you want to add other fields to your match stage expression too

Comment: can u please frame the query if possible to achieve the above result with aggregation?..In my use case i have take the aggregation result and update in one more collection..As this aggregation result will come null, if the field doesnt exist ..is there any possible way?

Comment: The aggregation framework doesn't play well with arrays, you have to unwind the arrays first using the unwind stage `$unwind`, please check out mongo reference doc for more information https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/

Comment: Why do you think *The aggregation framework doesn't play well with arrays*? can you elaborate? I would like to know.

Comment: @user3100115, for example, in a blog application, if you have a tag array for each blog entry in the database, and you want to display the top 10 blogs by tags, you can't really do it directly or it could be very hard, in that case, you have to unwind the collection using the $unwind stage, the do a {$sum:1}, on each individual tag on the $group stage, then sort the collection in descending order on each tag in the $sort stage, then a `{$limit:10}` stage to get the first 10. Without unwinding the collection first on tags, it would be really hard which was what I meant by not play with arays.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with the question asked here. Also it's not a reason to claim that *The aggregation framework doesn't play well with arrays*

Comment: @user3100115 You asked, I answered, what is the problem? The initial answer I posted was a potential solution from my perspective, my initial answer did not diverge from the question asked