# Is is possible perform aggregation on a collection and update the same collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-java

```
{ "_id" : 1, "quizzes" : [ 10, 6, 7 ], "labs" : [ 5, 8 ], "final" : 80, "midterm" : 75 ,"extraMarks":10}
{ "_id" : 2, "quizzes" : [ 9, 10 ], "labs" : [ 8, 8 ], "final" : 95, "midterm" : 80 }
{ "_id" : 3, "quizzes" : [ 4, 5, 5 ], "labs" : [ 6, 5 ], "final" : 78, "midterm" : 70 }
```

These are the documents in my collection.
Using the pipeline query as suggested in

[$add with some fields as Null returning sum value as Null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35250675/add-with-some-fields-as-null-returning-sum-value-as-null/35250863#35250863)

I am able to project the sum of fields using this query:

```
db.students.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "final": 1,
      "midterm": 1,
      "examTotal": {
        "$add": [
          "$final",
          "$midterm",
          {
            "$ifNull": [
              "$extraMarks",
              0
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Now we have to update the students collection a new field called total as field similar to exam total in the above projection?

Comment: Plain and simple: No.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Actually it depends on what you mean by *NO*. You can iterate the cursor result and update your documents using "bulk" operations.

Comment: @user3100115 That goes without saying and basically is the same argument as "If I take the data and insert it, it will be inserted". And if I may ask you to put your attention to *"**in** the above projection?"*

Answer (score 0):

Starting from MongoDB 4.2, you can [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/).

```
db.students.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "total": {
        "$add": [
          "$final",
          "$midterm",
          {
            "$ifNull": [
              "$extraMarks",
              0
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Negi1vPstFE) for your reference.